# laravel change message bug variable names

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have two models, which are `NextPage` and `MasterInformation`. However, I have one view for them. That view has input fields. when the user submits the form, I need to validate the data.
I do that like this:

```
$dataMasterInformation = [
    'container' => Input::get('container')
];
$dataNextPage = [
    'xpath' => 'next_page_xpath',
    'prefix' => 'next_page_prefix',
    'suffix' => 'next_page_suffix'
];
$validationMasterInformation = Validator::make($dataMasterInformation, MasterInformation::$rules);
$validationNextPage = Validator::make($dataNextPage, NextPage::$rules);
if(($validationMasterInformation->passes()) && ($validationNextPage->passes())){}else{
    return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validationNextPage->messages()->merge($validationMasterInformation));
}
```

The `rules` of the `NextPage` model is:

```
public static $rules = array(
    'xpath' =>'required'
);
```

The `rules` of the `MasterInformation` Model is:

```
public static $rules = array(
    'container' => 'required'
);
```

My blade code for the view is:

```
<li>
    {{Form::text('container', '', array('placeholder' => 'Container'))}}
    <span>{{$errors->first('container')}}</span>
</li>
<li>
    {{Form::text('next_page_xpath', '', array('placeholder' => 'Next Page Xpath'))}}
    <span>{{$errors->first('next_page')}}</span>
</li>
<li>
    {{Form::text('next_page_prefix', '', array('placeholder' => 'Next Page Prefix'))}}
    <span>{{$errors->first('next_page_prefix')}}</span>
</li>
<li>
    {{Form::text('next_page_suffix', '', array('placeholder' => 'Next Page Suffix'))}}
    <span>{{$errors->first('next_page_suffix')}}</span>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</li>
```

#### My problem

The names in the rules are different from the names in the form. Thus, if there are errors with the entered data, I can discover them but I am not able to use them in the `$errors->first()` variable in the blade code.

How to solve that please?

I know that I could use the exact names, but, unfortunately, I couldn't because there would be conflicts in the names since the models share some same variable names.

Comment: @lozadaOmr your edit introduced 2 syntax errors, take more care when editing in the future.

Answer (score 0):

i could be wrong, but if i remember correctly, the $errors is a MessageBag type, which means for each message, it actually has a key which might has something to do with the input name.

if you dd($errors), it might help, here's the doc for MessageBag, http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Support.MessageBag.html. What I used most is get(), and merge(), and has().